# Centering unordered list of images

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a horizontal list of image links, though it seems that the left of the images are being centered. As you can see, the center of the list of images (which are all the same size) is slightly to the right of the text.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id='nav'>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href=''><img src='images/login.png' /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=''><img src='images/add.png' /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=''><img src='images/forum.png' /></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#nav {
    text-align: center;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 30px;
}
```

What can I do to completely center it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/3d6TS/**

The `<ul>` tag by default adds padding. You need to set `padding:0` manually to `<ul>` tag.

```
#nav ul {
   list-style: none;
   margin: 20px auto;
   padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #nav  { text-align: center; }
 #nav ul { list-style: none; }
 #nav ul li { display: inline; }
```

the solution is the display:inline on the li

Comment: The same thing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution would be to maintain the margin-left and make sure the first child has a left margin of 0. This causes both the first and last children to have no margins on the edges it meets with the parent. This is good as `:first-child` doesn't catastrophically break styles in >=ie7 where as `:last-child` is unsupported in <=ie8 making the reverse of this infeasible for the time being.

```
#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:30px;
}

#nav ul li:first-child {
    margin-left:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I was mistaken when I thought that I'd fixed it. My solution only appeared to make it look more centered, though in fact if I increased the margin to 60px, the same result would appear. I just tried this solution and once again, I get the exact same result.